# How to change keycode?

Tags: keyboard

I made a mistake changing the <kbd>C</kbd> keystroke into the numbersign, so every time I type <kbd>C</kbd> in keyboard, the display show numbersign instead. How can I change it back?

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: I follow an instruction on a website like this: xmodmap -e "keycode 54 shift = numbersign asciitilde"

Comment: Have you entered into any file or started only the command in the terminal? Describe in more detail in your question what you've done. And maybe even the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you changed it with `xmodmap -e "keycode 54 shift = numbersign asciitilde"`.

To change this back, you can run

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 54 shift = c C"
```

Since you can't type "c" and "C", you can either copy-paste the command from here, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then either "63" for lowercase "c", or "43" for uppercase "C", and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.